# Buscar archivos .php que contengan una cierta variable

Tags: php, wordpress

Me encuentro modificando algunos documentos .php desde el administrador de archivos del hosting y quisiera saber si es posible identificar cuales archivos del servidor contienen una determinada variable. Esto principalmente para identificar de donde provienen los valores que toman las mismas. 
Estoy iniciando en wordpress, trabajando con plugins ya hechos y me considero un dummy para php, así que sería de gran utilidad cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿El servidor es Linux o Windows? ¿Tienes acceso SSH? Si es Linux y tienes acceso entonces puedes utilizar `grep` desde la consola para buscar un patrón de texto (en este caso, la variable en cuestión) en todos tus archivos PHP. Aunque por otro lado si tienes una copia local del proyecto quizá te sea más fácil abrirlo con tu editor de código, por ejemplo Sublime Text, que incluye funciones para hacer este tipo de búsquedas.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta. Quizás lo más sencillo sea lo segundo, uso dicho editor de código pero se puede hacer una búsqueda en todos los archivos que se encuentren dentro de un mismo directorio? O tendría que ir abriendo uno por uno y buscar dicha variable?

Comment: Sí, en general siempre es más sencillo y rápido hacer esta búsqueda desde el propio editor de código.  Y sí, puedes buscar en todo el directorio sin tener que abrir los archivos de uno en uno. He escrito una respuesta con el ejemplo de como hacerlo en Sublime Text (los pasos serán similares para cualquier otro editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos maneras principales de buscar un patrón de texto entre todos tus archivos: o bien utilizar una herramienta del sistema operativo o utilizar tu propio editor de código.

**Ejemplos:**

**Linux**

`grep -rnw '/mi/directorio/wordpress' -e 'patrón'`

`grep` es una herramienta que imprimirá a la consola todas las líneas que coincidan con el patrón.

- `-r` o `-R` para hacer una búsqueda recursiva
- `-n` para mostrar el número de la línea
- `-w` para coincidir con la palabra entera

Para ver todas las opciones, mírate la documentación: https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep

También puedes utilizar expresiones regulares (RegExp) para búsquedas avanzadas. Para aprender más: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Para guardar los resultados de un búsqueda `grep` haz:

`grep -rnw '/mi/directorio/wordpress' -e 'patrón' > resultados.txt`

**Sublime Text 3**

Sublime Text es un editor de código popular que incluye una función para buscar entre todos tus archivos (al igual que la mayoría de editores de código).

Para buscar en Sublime (versión en inglés):

1. Haz clic en `Project` -> `Add Folder to Project...`
2. Selecciona el directorio donde quieres hacer la búsqueda
3. Haz clic en `Find` -> `Find in Files...`
4. Introduce tu búsqueda en el campo `Find`
5. Especifica el directorio en el campo `Where` (también puedes buscar fuera de esta carpeta/proyecto)
6. Ignora el campo de `Replace`
7. Haz clic en `Find` y los resultados te aparecerán

Adjunto foto de una búsqueda para `$post` en un proyecto de WordPress:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]